# How to use click() to proceed to next form elements and hide current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, show-hide

What do I mean is that I would have a form of questions but each question can only proceed after clicking next button. So let's say 1st question appear, click next, it will hide the 1st question and show the 2nd question and so on.

I managed to show the 2nd question but unable to proceed to the 3rd question, and ended up the logic messed up. I need to continue to the 3rd question. After reaching the 3rd question, which is the last one, the next button will switch to submit button.

How can I change the js to proceed to the 3rd question?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <form action="" id="theform">
        <div class="qn 1st">
            <p>Qn 1</p>
            <input type="radio" name="qn1" id="one" value="one"><label for="one">one</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="qn1" id="two" value="two"><label for="two">two</label>
        </div>
        <div class="qn 2nd">
            <p>Qn 2</p>
            <input type="radio" name="qn2" id="yes" value="yes"><label for="yes">yes</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="qn2" id="no" value="no"><label for="no">no</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="qn2" id="neutral" value="neutral"><label for="neutral">no</label>
        </div>
        <div class="qn 3rd">
            <p>Qn 3</p>
            <input type="radio" name="qn3" id="ohyeah" value="ohyeah"><label for="ohyeah">ohyeah</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="qn3" id="ohno" value="ohno"><label for="ohno">ohno</label>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#next").click(function(){
        $(".qn").each(function(i){

            if($(this).is(":visible")){
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else if($(this).next().is(":hidden")){
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

JsFiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/wcogrmpq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    var current = $(".qn:visible"),
        total = $(".qn").length,
        last = $(".qn:last");
    $(current).next().show();
    $(current).hide();
    if ($(current).next().is(last)) {//check if it is last question
        $("#next").hide();
        $("input[type='submit']").show();
    }
});
```

See [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcogrmpq/6/) here.

Comment: For checking the last question, can I use this if($(".qn").is(":last-child")) ?

Comment: Hmm.. I tried and it doesn't work. Any idea? Anyway, yours works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. Use a selector to find the visible question. Then hide that one and show the next one.

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    var current = $(".qn:visible");
    current.hide();
    current.next().show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wcogrmpq/2/)

If you're into one-liners, it can be written as:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $(".qn:visible").hide().next().show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the one liner.

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#next").click(function(){
        $(".qn:visible:first").hide().next().show();                
    });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wcogrmpq/3/)